# Changing theme using web method

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am changing page theme based on dropdown selection. Before it was written in user control with code behind, The same code i put in web method in handler page and through ajax call i am calling this method. but theme is not changing for the page.

Below is my code:

```html
    [WebMethod(MessageName = "GetAndSetTheme")]
    public string GetAndSetTheme(string themeName)
    {
        string strValue = "";
        Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");

        PagesSection pages = (PagesSection)config.GetSection("system.web/pages");

        pages.Theme = themeName;

        if (!pages.SectionInformation.IsLocked)
        {

            config.Save();
            strValue = themeName;
        }
        return strValue;

    }
```

Here i am passing theme name.
And below is my jquery code:

```html
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ddlTheme").change(function () {
            debugger;
            var themeValue = $('option:selected', this).text();
            if (this.val() > 0) {
                SetTheme(themeValue);
                $("#ddlTheme").attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    });
    function SetTheme(theme)
    {
        var param = JSON.stringify({ themeName: theme });
        var protocol = "http://localhost:1469/";
        var url = protocol + "CMSPages/WebService.asmx/GetAndSetTheme"
        $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
            options.async = true;
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: param,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#ddlTheme").attr('disabled', false);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

That is working fine but just need to refresh the page.

I have html content inside div but when i am using this code which is below:

```html
$("#RefreshTheme").load('file:///D:/Newfolder/Header.html');
```

this code is inside ajax success.

But i am getting error in console that is cannot load file "this file name", Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** of all having Cross origin domain problem locally with `file://` is browser related , and you can overcome it by following instructions here [Bypass CORS Errors When Testing APIs Locally](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/08/bypass-cors-errors-testing-apis-locally/)

**Second** : changing the theme using async request will not affect until you refresh the page (do a postback) .

but there is another workaround : you can simply change the url of your css files using javascript and it will load the new theme instantly

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, Your second solution changing css files using javascript worked for me. Thank you very much. I am marking it as answer.

Comment: @AkashKumar Glad to help :)